# Ruby blocks with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading the Eloquent Ruby book (awesome book so far) and don't understand one section that talks about blocs, params, and scope. Here's the code...

```
class SomeApplication
# Rest of the class omitted...
  def do_something 
    with_logging('load', nil) { @doc = Document.load( 'book' ) }

    # Do something with the document...

    with_logging('save', @doc) { |the_object| the_object.save } 
  end

  def with_logging(description, the_object) 
    begin
      @logger.debug( "Starting #{description}" )
      yield( the_object )
      @logger.debug( "Completed #{description}" ) 
    rescue
      @logger.error( "#{description} failed!!")
      raise 
    end
  end 
end
```

The book says the code is more complex than it needs to be because @doc is automatically visible inside the code block. So there's no need to pass it down as an argument.

I don't understand which param he's talking about, the @doc or `|the_object|`. What would this code look like after changing it to remove the unnecessary complexity?

Or does it mean that the @doc that was created in `with_logging('load', nil)` is what is still visible? Even if that's the case I'm not sure how the `with_logging` method at the bottom would access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@doc` is an [instance variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html). It is defined within the scope of an object (in this case, the instance of the class `SomeApplication`), and is typically used to store a value that "belongs" to the instance. Instance variables are always available to the instance methods of an object. They are not available outside the object, unless you make them into attributes.

Your confusion re: the example probably stems from the roundabout way in which the author is passing the value from the method `do_something` to the method `with_logging`. When `with_logging` is called, it receives two arguments, `'save'` and `@doc`. In `with_logging` the local variable `description` is set to `'save'`, and the local variable `the_object` is set to `@doc`. Then `yield` is called with the argument `the_object`, This passes `the_object` to the code block defined in the second call to `with_logging`, which you can think of as sort of anonymous function. But of course, as the author points out, `@doc` was already set in the first call to `with_logging`, so it is unnecessary to pass it around as an argument. He could have written the second function call as:

```
with_logging('save') { @doc.save }
```

and the first as:

```
with_logging('load') { @doc = Document.load('book') }
```

then call `yield` with no arguments, and the effect would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks (and lambdas/procs) are closures.  This means that they can access any variables in the environment they are created in.  `@doc` is an instance variable, so it is always in scope in the context of the class.  `@doc` is the value that is bound to `the_object`, which is unnecessary.  The revised code would look like:

```
class SomeApplication
  # Rest of the class omitted...
  def do_something 
    with_logging('load') { @doc = Document.load( 'book' ) }

    # Do something with the document...

    with_logging('save') { @doc.save } 
  end

  def with_logging(description) 
    begin
      @logger.debug( "Starting #{description}" )
      yield
      @logger.debug( "Completed #{description}" ) 
    rescue
      @logger.error( "#{description} failed!!")
      raise 
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an instance variable (indicated by the @) so is available throughout the class, in any method.